# Group words (from defined list) into themes in R

Tags: r

I am new to Stackoverflow and trying to learn R.

I want to find a set of defined words in a text. Return the count of these words in a table format with the associated theme I have defined.

Here is my attempt:

```
text <- c("Green fruits are such as apples, green mangoes and avocados are good for high blood pressure. Vegetables range from greens like lettuce, spinach, Swiss chard, and mustard greens are great for heart disease. When researchers combined findings with several other long-term studies and looked at coronary heart disease and stroke separately, they found a similar protective effect for both. Green mangoes are the best.")

library(qdap)

**#Own Defined Lists**

fruit <- c("apples", "green mangoes", "avocados") 
veg <- c("lettuce", "spinach", "Swiss chard", "mustard greens")

**#Splitting in Sentences**

stext <- strsplit(text, split="\\.")[[1]] 

**#Obtain and Count Occurences**
library(plyr) 
fruitres <- laply(fruit, function(x) grep(x, stext))
vegres <- laply(veg, function(x) grep(x, stext))

**#Quick check, and not returning 2 results for** "green mangoes"
grep("green mangoes", stext)

**#Trying with stringr package**
tag_ex <- paste0('(', paste(fruit, collapse = '|'), ')')
tag_ex

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


themes = sapply(str_extract_all(stext, tag_ex), function(x) paste(x, collapse=','))[[1]]
themes     


#Create data table
library(data.table)
data.table(fruit,fruitres)
```

Using the respective qdap and stringr packages I am unable to obtain a solution I desire.

**Desired solution for fruits and veg combined in a table**

```
apples               fruit     1
green mangoes        fruit     2
avocados             fruit     1
lettuce              veg       1
spinach              veg       1
Swiss chard          veg       1
mustard greens       veg       1
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `grep("green mangoes", stext, ignore.case = TRUE)` will return 2 results

Answer (score 1):

I tried to generalize for `N` number of vectors

#### tidyverse and stringr solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
```

Create a `data.frame` of your vectors

```
data <- c("fruit","veg")   # vector names
L <- map(data, ~get(.x))
names(L) <- data
long <- map_df(1:length(L), ~data.frame(category=rep(names(L)[.x]), type=L[[.x]]))

# You may receive warnings about coercing to characters

#   category           type
# 1    fruit         apples
# 2    fruit  green mangoes
# 3    fruit       avocados
# etc
```

To count instances of each

```
long %>%
  mutate(count=str_count(tolower(text), tolower(type)))
```

#### Output

```
  category           type count
1    fruit         apples     1
2    fruit  green mangoes     2
3    fruit       avocados     1
4      veg        lettuce     1
# etc
```

#### Extra stuff

We can add another vector easily

```
health <- c("blood", "heart")
data <- c("fruit","veg", "health")

# code as above
```

#### Extra output (`tail`)

```
6      veg    Swiss chard     1
7      veg mustard greens     1
8   health          blood     1
9   health          heart     2
```